# Natural deduction proof for new var

Tags: logic

> Show by natural deduction,
>
> $$(x \vee y) \vdash ((x \wedge z) \vee (z \implies y))$$

I have tried using $$(z \implies y)$$ as my assumption, but that didn't work out too well.

Where can I go?

Comment: Hint: $\vdash z\vee \neg z$

Comment: The statement isn't constructively true.  So you have to use law of excluded middle.  But you should be able to prove or disprove any propositional logic statement if you have LEM at your disposal, it is just the same as using truth tables in the language of natural deduction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of proving it using purely the rules of natural deduction:

\begin{array}{l}
& \{1\} & 1. & x \lor y & \text{ $Prem.$ }\\
& \{2\} & 2. & x & \text{ Assum. (1st Disj.) }\\
& \{3\} & 3. & z & \text{ Assum. }\\
& \{2,3\} & 4. & x \land z & \text{ 2,3 $\land$I }\\
& \{2,3\} & 5. & (x \land z) \lor (z \implies y) & \text{ 4 $\lor$I }\\
& \{2\} & 6. & z \implies ((x \land z) \lor (z \implies y)) & \text{ 3,5 CP }\\
& \{7\} & 7. & \neg z & \text{ Assum. }\\
& \{8\} & 8. & \neg y & \text{ Assum. }\\
& \{3,8\} & 9. & \neg y \land z & \text{ 3,8 $\land$I }\\
& \{3,8\} & 10. & z & \text{ 9 $\land$E }\\
& \{3\} & 11. & \neg y \implies z & \text{ 8,10 CP }\\
& \{3,7\} & 12. & \neg \neg y & \text{ 7,11 MT }\\
& \{3,7\} & 13. & y & \text{ 12 DNE }\\
& \{7\} & 14. & z \implies y & \text{ 3,13 CP }\\
& \{7\} & 15. & (x \land z) \lor (z \implies y) & \text{ 14 $\lor$I }\\
& - & 16. & \neg z \implies ((x \land z) \lor (z \implies y)) & \text{ 7,15 CP }\\
& \{17\} & 17. & \neg ((x \land z) \lor (z \implies y)) & \text{ Assum. }\\
& \{17\} & 18. & z & \text{ 16,17 MT, DNE }\\
& \{2,17\} & 19. & \neg z & \text{ 6,17 MT }\\
& \{2,17\} & 20. & z \land \neg z & \text{ 18,19 $\land$I }\\
& \{2\} & 21. & (x \land z) \lor (z \implies y) & \text{ 17,20 RAA (1st Concl.)}\\
& \{22\} & 22. & y & \text{ Assum. (2nd Disj.) }\\
& \{3,22\} & 23. & y \land z & \text{ 3,22 $\land$I }\\
& \{3,22\} & 24. & y & \text{ 23 $\land$E }\\
& \{22\} & 25. & z \implies y & \text{ 3,24 CP }\\
& \{22\} & 26. & (x \land z) \lor (z \implies y) & \text{ 26 $\lor$I (2nd Concl.)}\\
& \{1\} & 27. & (x \land z) \lor (z \implies y)& \text{ 1,2,21,22,26 $\lor$E }\\
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

In the formula that has to be derived we have a logical disjunction as a major logical connective and we know that $p\to q \leftrightarrow \neg p\lor q$. Keeping these two things in mind helps us picking the appropriate assumption $z\land\neg y$.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
& \{1\} & (1) & x\lor y & \text {Premise}\\
& \{2\} & (2) & z \land\neg y & \text {Assumption}\\
& \{2\} & (3) & \neg y & \text {2 Simplification}\\
& \{1,2\} & (4) & x & \text {1,3 Modus tollendo ponens}\\
& \{2\} & (5) & z & \text {2 Simplification}\\
& \{1,2\} & (6) & x\land z & \text {4,5 Adjunction}\\
& \{1\} & (7) & (z\land\neg y)\to(x\land z) & \text {2,6 Conditional Proof}\\
& \{1\} & (8) & \neg(z\land\neg y)\lor(x\land z) & \text {7 Equivalence for Implication and Disjunction}\\
& \{1\} & (9) & (\neg z\lor y)\lor(x\land z) & \text {8 De Morgan's Law}\\
& \{1\} & (10) & (x\land z)\lor(z\to y) & \text {9 Equivalence for Implication and Disjunction and Commutative Law}\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First 4 lines of a proof using a simplified form of natural deduction:

1. $X\lor Y\space$  (Premise, two cases to consider)
2. $Z\lor \neg Z\space$  (Law of excluded middle, two sub-cases to consider)
3. $X\space$  (Premise, case 1)
4. $Z\space$  (Premise, sub-case 1)

In every case and sub-case, you should be able to obtain $[X\land Y] \lor [Z\implies Y].$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using natural deduction with a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

[image]

The overall strategy was to use the law of the excluded middle (LEM) on $Z \lor \lnot Z$.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: You can economise that second sub:proof, *a lot*. You are assuming $\neg z$ on line 12 aiming to derive $z\to y$ (line 27).  Now look at lines 18 through to  22.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think you are right. Lines 13 to 26 could be replaced by the subproof on lines 19 through 21.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$
Here's a proof by contradiction.
$${\fitch{~~1.~x\vee y\qquad\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~2.~\neg((x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y))\qquad\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{~~3.~z\qquad\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{~~4.~x\qquad\textsf{Assumption}}{~~5.~x\wedge z\qquad\textsf{Conjunction Introduction (3,4)}\\~~6.~(x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y)\qquad\textsf{Disjunction Introduction (5)}\\~~7.~\bot\qquad\textsf{Negation Elimination (2,6)}\\~~8.~y\qquad\textsf{Ex Falso Quodlibet (7)}}\\~~9.~x\to y\qquad\textsf{Conditional Introduction (4-8)}\\\fitch{10.~y\qquad\textsf{Assumption}}{}\\11.~y\to y\qquad\textsf{Conditional Introduction (10-10)}\\12.~y\qquad\textsf{Disjunction Elimination (1,9,11)}}\\13.~z\to y\qquad\textsf{Conditional Introduction (3-12)}\\14.~(x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y)\qquad\textsf{Disjunction Introduction (13)}\\15.~\bot\qquad\textsf{Negation Elimination (2,14)}}\\16.~\neg\neg((x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y))\qquad\textsf{Negation Introduction (2-15)}\\17.~(x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y)\qquad\textsf{Double Negation Elimination (16)}}\\\therefore \quad x\vee y\vdash (x\wedge z)\vee(z\to y)}$$